Getting Ventoy v1.0.99 to work with secure boot turned on
I am trying to create a dual boot Live USB of Ubuntu 22.04.4LTS and Windows 10, using Ventoy v1.0.99
When I first created the Ventoy Live USB, I was getting "Verification failed: (0x1A) Security Violation Error" when booting it, despite each of the OS' above booting fine on the USB's I got images off.
Then I found the guide (on Reddit) to mount a recent version of Linux, and copy the files BOOTX64.efi and mmx64.efi from the other Linux to /EFI/BOOT in VentoyEFI. And rename grub.efi in /EFI/BOOT in VentoyEFI to grubx64.efi.
However this changed nothing.
Next I moved grubx64.efi from the working version of Linux Live CD I had included in the Ventoy system (on a hunch), to the VentoyEFI, and it booted to the below, no security warning.

Evidently there is a key (still, from reading about issues with Ventoy version 1.0.98) that grub in Ubuntu 22.04.4LTS needs to have copied ?into the BOOT64.efi of the VentoyEFI, to make that system work, no?
How do I get the key in Grub into the boot system of Ventoy?

It should work without any additional tweaking: https://ventoy.net/en/doc_secure.html

I would suggest if that was the case, that page I have seen already wouldn't have "if this doesn't work" workaround steps on it.

Do you mean this part (my bold): However the solution is not perfect enough. If you get some error screen instead of the above blue screen (for example, Linpus lite xxxx). It means that the secure boot solution doesn't work with your machine, so you need to turn off the option, and disable secure boot in the BIOS. Is that the case you're experiencing? Also nowhere is mentionend anything remotely similar to what you said you tried (copying bootloaders).

The help provided for this program didn't help, so I went looking on the likes of Reddit for a solution. Seeing as a bootloader (Grub) is loading sans a security warning, I trust the issue is the bootloader that is first loaded with Ventoy doesn't have an up to date signature, and instead one on a blocked list. Can you help me with that, sans anything on the Ventoy website?

It isn't a one time thing. This is to image 200 laptops. I do wonder how someone in IT just survives solely on manufacturer provided solutions.
